# Why do I get a syntax error when trying to test for correct user input?

Tags: python

```
print ("Hello, and welcome to TEXT RPG!")
name = input("Would you be so kind as to tell us your name?")
print (""+Name+" Is it? What a stupid, stupid name!")
print ("And you, "+Name+" are a stupid, stupid child.!")
print ("However. There is hope for your worthless being yet!")
print ("I will train you and make you less of a worthless being.")

accept1 = input("Do you accept?")

while accept1 = "Yes" "No" "no" "yes" "n" "y":
    print ("Alright then! Let us begin!")
else:
    print ("That's not an answer you insolent brat!")
    accept1 = input("Do you accept?")
```

For some reason I get a syntax error with no red bar. Can anyone help? I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: syntax error.  that's all. no red bar or anything else.

Comment: @Necrex: you mean your *editor* tells you this? If Python tells you this you'll get a more informative error.

Comment: Note that `"Yes" "No" "no" "yes" "n" "y"` evaluates to `"YesNonoyesny"`. I would strongly recommend you find and follow an introductory tutorial.

Comment: I ran it, 3.5.0 Shell opened, and I got a syntax error. Looking at the original window, no red bars appeared.

Comment: @Jonsharpe I put commas after each word. I thought the same as you did, but it still has a syntax error.

Comment: Just ran it in shell, got this error. SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement.     `print ("Hello, and welcome to TEXT RPG!")---RED--BAR---`

Comment: @Necrex: when you get this solved, remember to come back here and "accept" your favourite answer.  This helps StackOverflow properly retire the question.

Answer (score 5):

There are three errors with

```
while accept1 = "Yes" "No" "no" "yes" "n" "y":
```

1. You cannot use assignment in a `while` statement, you need to use `==`, not `=` there. This is the source of your syntax error:

   ```
   >>> while accept1 = "Yes" "No" "no" "yes" "n" "y":
     File "<stdin>", line 1
       while accept1 = "Yes" "No" "no" "yes" "n" "y":
                     ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```
2. You created a test for the string `"YesNonoyesny"`, as Python automatically concatenates consecutive strings. If you wanted to test for multiple possible values, use a *containment test*.
3. `while` creates an endless loop, since if the test is true, you never change `accept1` in the loop and the condition will be forever true. Use `if` here instead.

This works:

```
if accept1 in {"Yes", "No", "no", "yes", "n", "y"}:
```

because that creates a *set* of strings to test again, and the `accept1 in ...` test is true if the value of `accept1` is a member of the set.

You could make the test a little more compact and flexible by using `str.lower()`:

```
if accept1.lower() in {"yes", "no", "n", "y"}:
```

If you still need a loop, include asking the question in the loop. Just make it endless and use `break` to end it instead:

```
while True:
    accept1 = input("Do you accept?")
    if accept1.lower() in {"yes", "no", "n", "y"}:
        break        
    print ("That's not an answer you insolent brat!")

print ("Alright then! Let us begin!")
```

Comment: So, all I did was add brackets so it looked like `while accept1.lower() ("y", "yes", "n", "no")` and it worked.

Comment: @Martijin I only added that because I thought that's what was wrong. I ended up creating an entirely new loop that worked just fine for me. `while ___.lower() == ("__", "__"):
    print ("ANYTHING")
else:
    print ("something")
    originalinput = input("Do you accept?")`

Comment: @Necrex: that won't do what you want, not with `==`

Answer (score 1):

You have two different variables: "name" and "Name".

Also, your while loop has incorrect logic.  Instead, think in terms of "loop until I get acceptable input".  What you have will be an infinite loop on any of the expected inputs.

```
while accept1 not in ["Yes", "No", "no", "yes", "n", "y"]:
    print ("That's not an answer, you insolent brat!")
    accept1 = input("Do you accept?")
```